# How to make the currency symbol display after the numbers and add a space between them in PrestaShop 1.7.4.2

Tags: prestashop, currency, prestashop-1.7

**Hello!**
Since the 1.7 update of PrestaShop you cannot customize the currency any longer. In my theme by default, the currency symbol displays right before the numbers, without any space. But it should be exactly opposite, symbol after the numbers with a space between them. If anyone knew a way around I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I could explain here, but there are a lot of tutorials in the web, which I think can be more useful, here one to change the symbol: https://zemez.io/prestashop/support/how-to/prestashop-1-7-%D1%81hange-currency-symbol/

If you want to change the position of the symbol, you need

1. Go to `translations/cldr/main--xx-XX--numbers` file (where xx-XX is your language, en-EN, de-DE or ru-RU). Open this file with any code editor.
2. Find something like this `"accounting":"` and `"standard"` and move the `\u00a0` to the start or end, depending on where you want to place the symbol.

For example I will move the symbol from the start to the end en-US numbers.

Before: `"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.00;(\u00a4#,##0.00)","standard":"\u00a4#,##0.00"`
After: `"accounting":"#,##0.00\u00a4;(#,##0.00\u00a4)","standard":"#,##0.00\u00a4"`

Hpe this help!

Comment: It won't solve my problem. There isn't A LOT of these tutorials, I've found 3 which are up to date. Zemez is actually developer of my theme, unfortunately my support has expired. I don't want to change the symblo of the currency, but change it's position so that it displays after the numbers with a space between them. I'm pretty sure it has to be done in the main--xx-Xx--numbers file

Comment: can you tell us which one is the current iso code of the currency you are using, and the final format you want to have?

Comment: ISO code of my currency looks like this - PLN / 985. In the shop it displays as PLNxx,xx where x are numbers. I want it to display like so - xx,xx PLN where xx are numbers of course.

Comment: Ok I have added and explanation how to change the location of the symbol also.

Comment: Hey, thanks for Your answer. Unfortunately I couldn't get this solution to work. No matter what I've put in both accounting and standard, the price format stayed unchanged on the site. I would be glad if You would say exactly how should I edit this piece of code, maybe that's the case but I doubt it. Here it is - "accounting":"#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4;(#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4)","standard":"\u00a4\u00a0#,##0.00"

Comment: Clear the cache, this works because I have tested before edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

If somebody searching for changing currency sign on PS 1.7.6.

Now it is in the table ps_currency_lang

Via admin panel cannot be changed at the momen, only phpmyadmin  :(